# Kendo UI Chart Colors

Tags: javascript, jquery, telerik, kendo-ui

I'm having trouble configuring the bar colors for a Kendo UI column chart. Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="chart"></div>
    <script src="js/thirdParty/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/thirdParty/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            var data,
                dataSource;
            data = [{
                type: "C1",
                amount: 100,
                year: 2008,
                color: "red"
            }, {
                type: "C2",
                amount: 120,
                year: 2008,
                color: "blue"
            }, {
                type: "C2",
                amount: 50,
                year: 2009,
                color: "blue"
            }, {
                type: "C1",
                amount: 10,
                year: 2010,
                color: "red"
            }, {
                type: "C1",
                amount: 120,
                year: 2011,
                color: "red"
            }, {
                type: "C2",
                amount: 50,
                year: 2011,
                color: "blue"
            }];
            dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
                data: data,
                group: {
                    field: "type"
                },
                sort: { field: "year" }
            });
            $("#chart").kendoChart({
                dataSource: dataSource,
                series: [{
                    type: "column",
                    field: "amount",
                    categoryField: "year",
                    name: "#= group.value #",
                    colorField: "color"
                }],
            })
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm trying to get "C1" to be **red** and "C2" to be **blue** but the chart renders like in the following screen shot:

[image]

Any pointers in the right direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

After looking into this further, I found that **colorField** is for setting color to a single point in the series (not to the entire series). I found **[seriesColors](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/dataviz/chart#configuration-seriesColors)** was what I was looking for:

http://docs.kendoui.com/api/dataviz/chart#configuration-seriesColors

Here is my refactored example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="chart"></div>
    <script src="js/thirdParty/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/thirdParty/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            var data,
                dataSource;
            data = [{
                type: "C1",
                amount: 100,
                year: 2008
            }, {
                type: "C2",
                amount: 120,
                year: 2008
            }, {
                type: "C2",
                amount: 50,
                year: 2009
            }, {
                type: "C1",
                amount: 10,
                year: 2010
            }, {
                type: "C1",
                amount: 120,
                year: 2011
            }, {
                type: "C2",
                amount: 50,
                year: 2011
            }];
            dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
                data: data,
                group: {
                    field: "type"
                },
                sort: { field: "year" }
            });
            $("#chart").kendoChart({
                dataSource: dataSource,
                seriesColors: ["red", "blue"],
                series: [{
                    type: "column",
                    field: "amount",
                    categoryField: "year",
                    name: "#= group.value #"
                }],
            })
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

check the JS Fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/9VZdS/45/

```
$(function() {
    var dataset = new Array(1,2,3,null,5,6);
    var highlighted = new Array(null,null,null,4,null,null);

    $('#chart').kendoChart({
        theme: 'metro',
        seriesDefaults: {
            type: 'column',
            stack: true
        },
        series: [
            {
                name: 'Not Highlighted',
                data: dataset,
                color: 'red'
            },
            {
                name: 'Highlighted',
                data: highlighted,
                color: 'blue'
            }
        ]
    })
});
```

Comment: Hello Arun, Do you have any idea of the following question  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30176594/multi-color-line